# Javascript Popup IE Error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, window

I've stepped into a new position and am tasked with cleaning up pre-existing code.  I will be posting a Javascript function for building hotel reservations by using a base URL and then carrying over variables to the other site.

More clearly, this function allows your to access Site A and search for hotel reservations on Site B.  The function makes this even clearer.

```
function buildReservationURL(){
  var site = "http://ach.travel.yahoo.net/hotel/HotelCobrand.do?smls=Y&Service=YHOE&.intl=us&.resform=YahooHotelsCity&";


 <!-- Variables Are Defined Here from Form Values //-->


  var finishedURL = site + "city=" + cityname + "&state=" + statename + "&dateLeavingDay=" + inDay + "&dateReturningDay=" + outDay + "&adults=" + adults + "&source=YX&distance=&hotelChain=&searchMode=city&cityCountryCode=us&&dateLeavingMonth=" + inMonth + "&dateReturningMonth=" + outMonth;
  NewWindow(finishedURL,'Yahoo Travel','780','580','yes','no','1');
}
```

However, I am receiving an error in IE that gives zero information.  The error occurs prior to a window being created so I feel the error would reside somewhere in the function where it is created and the URL is built.  This does work fine in FireFox.  Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to edit your code down to where the actual problem is happening. This is a mess.

Comment: Not sure how the function makes this "even clearer".  I'd zero in on the NewWindow function.  What is the definition of that function?

Comment: You say the error in IE gives "zero information".  That's probably not strictly true.  It may give very little information, but it probably says something, right?  What does the IE dialog box say, exactly?

Comment: The IE dialog box says "invalid Argument".

I believe the error is in the NewWindow line but I am unsure what it is.  I apologize for the code, like I said, I stepped into this.  I am just unsure what is preventing this.  From some research I think that the attributes defined for the window may be the cause.

Comment: Can you show the source of the `NewWindow` function?  It is almost certainly where the bug lies.

Comment: function NewWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll, menu, res){
    var winl = (screen.width - w) / 2;
    var wint = (screen.height - h) / 2;
    winprops = 'height=' + h + ',width=' + w + ',top=' + wint + ',left=' + winl + ',scrollbars=' + scroll + 
    ', resizable=' + res + ', location=no, directories=no, status=yes, menubar=' + menu;
    win = window.open(mypage,myname,winprops);
    if(parseInt(navigator.appVersion) > 3){
        win.window.focus();
    }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be you're using a version of IE that doesn't support spaces in the window name? ("Yahoo Travel" in your example.)

Comment: AFAIK - this affects all versions of IE (e.g. ...,6,7,8)

Comment: Had the same error, after removing the Spaces in the window name, the problem was solved. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use IE8's debugger and use "break on error." If it doesn't break in IE8, turn on compatibility view. That uses the IE7 javascript engine while still giving you IE8 debugging facilities.

Answer (score 1):

```
function NewWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll, menu, res) {
    var winl = (screen.width - w) / 2;
    var wint = (screen.height - h) / 2;
    winprops = 'height=' + h + ',width=' + w + ',top=' + wint + ',left=' + winl + ',scrollbars=' + scroll + 
    ', resizable=' + res + ', location=no, directories=no, status=yes, menubar=' + menu;
    win = window.open(mypage,myname,winprops);
    if(parseInt(navigator.appVersion) > 3){
        win.window.focus();
    }
}
```